# Setting Parameter variable to CSV value in Python

Tags: python, csv, parameters

I am encountering an error reading addresses from a CSV and setting a parameter to the result.  When the code

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for location in csv_reader:
            print(' ADDRESS: ' + location[0])
# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
# PARAMS = {'ff':location[0]}
```

is run the result is

```
 ADDRESS: 527 NE MONROE ST, PORTLAND, OR
 ADDRESS: 1129 SW 20TH AVE, PORTLAND, OR
 ADDRESS: 6511 N BURRAGE AVE, PORTLAND, OR
```

When the line

```
# PARAMS = {'ff':location[0]}
```

is uncommented, however, I get this error

```
... PARAMS = {'ff':location[0]}
  File "<stdin>", line 7
    PARAMS = {'ff':location[0]}
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you know how to fix this?  I am new to Python.  I have searched the posts on this site and have not found anything that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is very sensitive to indentation. Consider using an IDE such as vscode with python extension to prevent this kind of issue

Considering your comment, I will suppose that your use case is the following : you want to retrieve the first element which is the address of the location, and there is a lot of locations (one per line).

in that case, you can do the following which is easy to understand :

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    fst_elements_of_locations = []
    for location in csv_reader:
            print(' ADDRESS: ' + location[0])
            # add address of location into list 
            fst_elements_of_locations.append(location[0])
     # params['ff'] contains a list of all the address of locations
     PARAMS = {'ff':fst_elements_of_locations}
```

or more efficienly

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    PARAMS = {'ff':[location[0] for location in csv_reader]}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I need to set PARAMS to each address and then call a web service using the parameter.  Setting PARAMS to the last location only will not work.

Comment: I edited my answer considering your use case

Comment: Uh, what? You are just replacing the previous value over and over, and only retrieve the last one in the end.

Comment: The goal was to solve the syntax error issue, not to do the right thing, however thinking about it now it was stupid of me

Comment: Using the vscode IDE with python extension fixed the issue